# GitHub doesn't update GitHub page after git push -u origin main success

Tags: github-actions, push, github-pages, github-for-windows

I do the git push -u origin main but it doesn't upload to github page, then my terminal shows me this message:

```
Everything updated
'parent' branch set to track 'origin/parent'.
```

I wait 1 hour to see if it takes time to update but nothing changes on github page, does anyone know what could be happening?

[this are my .git folders at the moment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PemZ0.png)

Comment: "but it doesn't upload to github" How do you know?

Comment: sorry, I just saw and my main on github it was updated, what was not updated is the github page, how do I update the github page?

Comment: Your question doesn't mention GitHub Pages. Your question is about Git and pushing. Pushing worked, so there's no question to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this:

```
https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site
```

Every time you make a push request GitHub will update the github page automatically.

There are some requirements for a repo to be used as github pages.